# Как оптимизировать код?

Tags: php, dle

Собственно задача такая: есть таблица, в ней 3 поля (id,main,sub), id-просто индекс,  main - ид пользователя, кто пригласил, sub - кого пригласил.

Т.е это модуль для ДЛЕ для рефералов. И мне в админке нужно вывести список (табличку),
например, Юзер1 пригласил юзера2,3,4,5, а Юзер2 пригласил юзера 6,7,8.

Как мне кажется, цикл в цикле - не лучший вариант, т.к если 10 человек, каждый пригласил по 10 друзей, то это 110 запросов. А учитывая, что я еще получаю ИД по нику и количество его заказов, то это уже 310. Немало правда.

```
$db->query("SELECT distinct main FROM `" . PREFIX . "_refferal` LIMIT 10");
$db2 = new db;
$db3 = new db;

while ($row = $db->get_row()) {
    if ($bgcolor == "lightgrey") {
        $bgcolor = "white";
    } else {
        $bgcolor = "lightgrey";
    }
    $db3->query("SELECT name,skidka FROM `" . PREFIX . "_users` WHERE user_id='$row[main]'");
    $unf = $db3->get_row();
    $db3->query("SELECT id FROM `" . PREFIX . "_zakaz` WHERE user='$row[main]' AND (status='input' OR status='input')");
    $zk = $db3->num_rows();

    echo "<table border=0 width=600 align=center>
        <tr ><td  width=257 align=center bgcolor=$bgcolor><a href='?do=refferals&act=full&id=$row[main]'>$unf[name]</a> ($unf[skidka]%) Заказов : $zk</td>
        <td><table>";
    $db2->query("SELECT * FROM `" . PREFIX . "_refferal` WHERE main='$row[main]'");
    while ($row2 = $db2->get_row()) {
        $db3->query("SELECT name,skidka FROM `" . PREFIX . "_users` WHERE user_id='$row2[sub]'");
        $unf = $db3->get_row();
        $db3->query("SELECT id FROM `" . PREFIX . "_zakaz` WHERE user='$row2[sub]' AND (status='input' OR status='input')");
        $zk = $db3->num_rows();
        if ($bgcolor2 == "lightgreen") {
            $bgcolor2 = "white";
        } else {
            $bgcolor2 = "lightgreen";
        }
        echo "<tr bgcolor=$bgcolor2><td width=300><a href='?do=refferals&act=full&id=$row[main]'>$unf[name]<a/> ($unf[skidka]%) Заказов : $zk</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table></td></tr></table>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, я так понимаю работаешь ты через PDO или какую-то другую систему ORM. Во-вторых зачем так много дискрипторов подключения к базе создается я не понимаю, можно работать в контексте одного подключений. В-третьих, очень много лишних запросов, смотри в сторону JOIN-запросов.

Comment: Класс для базы Родной DLE
К сожелению вроде в контексте одного нельзя. Т.к если в большом цикле выполнить еще подзапрос, то предыдущий исчезает. 

Вот я тоже про джоин подумал, надо изучить их структуру

Comment: Тогда обязательно смотри в сторону JOIN потому что там ты можешь разрулить все парой (а то и вообще одним, если грамотно сможешь построить) единожды сделанных запросов и потом работать просто с полученными результатами не трогая больше базу. Значительно отразится на скорости работы в целом. Для примера, у нас в одном приложении сейчас выполняется JOIN через 18 таблиц и получается огромный массив с данными, с которыми потом работает остальной код, не трогая больше базу вообще. До этого там выполнялось куча промежуточных SELECT'ов и циклов.

Answer (score 2):

Согласен с ответом  Shamanis. Хочу еще пояснить. Допустим у нас есть таблица ваших приглашенных `refferal` с полями id,main,sub. И таблица заказов `zakaz` с полями main и zakaz_id. Делаем запрос к БД:

```
SELECT `refferal`.*, count(`zakaz`.`zakaz_id`) as `zakaz_count` FROM `refferal` INNER JOIN `zakaz` ON (`zakaz`.`main` = `refferal`.`main`) LIMIT 10
```

В ответе мы как раз видим всю информацию, которую КАК Я ПОНЯЛ вам нужно узнать:

```
id    main   sub   zakaz_count
1       1     3        3
2       1     2        3
3       2     4        2
4       3     5        1
и т.д.
```

Это Вам просто в качестве помощи. Конечно можно и получше сделать...